# react-native init AwesomeProject - fails to build

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I cannot get a vanilla react-native project to build immediately after running react-native init. I have not made any changes to the project, nor run other commands.

Commands/output:

```
> react-native init AwesomeProject
> cd AwesomeProject
> react-native run-ios
....
 ** BUILD FAILED **


The following commands produced analyzer issues:

    Analyze Base/RCTModuleMethod.mm normal x86_64
    Analyze RCTVibration.m normal x86_64
(2 commands with analyzer issues)

The following build commands failed:
    CompileC build/RCTVibration.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTVibration.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTVibration.o RCTVibration.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AwesomeProject57.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=164):
Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AwesomeProject57.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist


Error: Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AwesomeProject57.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:601:13)
    at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:621:13)
    at Promise.then (/Users/local/common/native-attempt/AwesomeProject57/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js:208:5)
    at <anonymous>
```

Mac OS X: 10.3.4
XCode: 9.4.1
react-native: 0.57
react: 16.5.0

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "AwesomeProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "0.57.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.45.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.5.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

After looking around StackOverflow, I tried:

- rm -rf node_modules
- rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*
- watchman watch-del-all

Using react-native run-ios still failed. FWIW, I did open the project in XCode and tried to build it there. I received a build error "/Users/local/common/native-attempt/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text/RawText/RCTRawTextViewManager.h:8:9: 'React/RCTViewManager.h' file not found". Different error, but I assume it is related.

Really pulling my hair out... any help appreciated.

Comment: I also got in the same issue. For now, you can initialize your project with a previous react-native version.  By using cmd:    react-native init AwesomeProject --version 0.56.0

Comment: I have a similar issue, regardless of the version I specify. Ex:

.../RCTLocationObserver.h:8:9: fatal error: 'React/RCTEventEmitter.h' file not found
#import <React/RCTEventEmitter.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1


** BUILD FAILED **


The following commands produced analyzer issues:
 Analyze Base/RCTModuleMethod.mm normal x86_64

Comment: Try replacing localhost with your IP address in X-Code Project. I am not sure that it will work but I used to have that error and it worked for me.